# runOnUiThread executes after waiting 30 seconds

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection, ui-thread

I came across an extremely weird behaviour related to code execution on UI thread after server data retrieval.

In onResume, I start a Thread where I wait for some server data fetch to complete and then run ui updates.

But the problem is that `runOnUiThread` command more often than not only starts executing after a delay of 30 seconds. It happens with some servers, but not with others, as per example below.

Here's the full code in onResume:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.e("TESTUI_1", "");

                String urlname = "https://stackoverflow.com";//runonuithread starts immediately
                //String urlname = "https://cnn.com";//runonuithread waits 30 seconds
                URL url = new URL(urlname);
                Log.e("TESTUI_1", urlname);
                HttpURLConnection connectionCache = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connectionCache.setDoOutput(true);

                connectionCache.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");//MAn680
                connectionCache.setRequestMethod("POST");//MAn680
                connectionCache.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");//MAn1140
                connectionCache.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                connectionCache.setReadTimeout(10000);
                connectionCache.setDoInput(true);//3.9.13
                connectionCache.setUseCaches(false); //3.9.13

                int status = connectionCache.getResponseCode();//3.9.12
                Log.e("TESTUI_status", ""+status);
                InputStream is;

                if (status >= 400) {
                    is = connectionCache.getErrorStream();
                } else {
                    is = connectionCache.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TESTUI_error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            long when = new Date().getTime();
            Log.e("TESTUI_2", ""+when);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long delta = new Date().getTime() - when;
                    Log.e("TESTUI_3", ""+delta);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


}
```

Logcat output with cnn.com:

> TESTUI_1                  E
> TESTUI_1                  E  https://cnn.com
> TESTUI_status             E  200
> TESTUI_2                  E  1693556722917
> TESTUI_3                  E  29643

Logcat output with stackoverflow.com:

> TESTUI_1                  E
> TESTUI_1                  E  https://stackoverflow.com
> TESTUI_status             E  200
> TESTUI_2                  E  1693556962546
> TESTUI_3                  E  230

Is there anything in the Logcat that I could search for?

Comment: I have no clue, why it is waiting for 30 seconds. Maybe this article will be some hint for you - https://medium.com/@yossisegev/understanding-activity-runonuithread-e102d388fe93. Also you can run in many problems with configuration change, memory leaks etc. if you will be using this code in Activity / Fragment alone. You should you for example ViewModel pattern with some business logic inside some "Use Case" or "Repository" pattern which will be calling your server. More work but it will pay off. See for example this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: So your whole story with a sleep of five seconds becoming thirty is fake.

Comment: not at all. The trigger for UI waiting 30 seconds is when there is a getResponseCode() running. Never seen anything like that. To note that our code runs fine since years, and it only shows this behaviour when we upgraded to tragetsdk33

Comment: So `Thread.sleep(5000)` is actually `getResponseCode()` which took 30 seconds?

Comment: I don't have a specific theory on why this happens, but could you add a debug output *after* the `runOnUiThread` call to see how long that call itself lasts (it should be very short).

Comment: If I am not wrong, doesn't https://cnn.com website has too much content to load if you notice, so definitely it'll take some time to process the request while SO website loads less resources. Also, your internet speed matters.

Answer (score 1):

`runOnUiThread` post a message to your main `Looper`'s `MessageQueue`, whose message is handled one by one.

So it's possible that `MessageQueue` is full of other message which took long time to process, which will result in long delay before your `Runnable` executed.

You can verify this by replace `runOnUiThread` with below code:

```
// this will insert your Runnable at the front of MessageQueue
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtFrontOfQueue(() -> {
    long delta = new Date().getTime() - start;
    Log.e("TESTUI2", "" + delta);
});
```

Comment: Tried this now, but with same result. App waits 30 seconds before running the Handler

Comment: Try to put `Log.e("TESTUI1", "" + start);` before `Thread.sleep(5000)` and check the result again?

Comment: The Thread starts immediately, placing the Log.e before the sleep shows that

Comment: Put also a log directly after the sleep.

Comment: cf. Edit. I could narrow it further down, but the thing has got even more obscure.

Comment: Please check the code for reproducing the problem

Comment: Just tested on my computer, `runOnUiThread ` started immediately for both `stackoverflow.com` and `cnn.com`. 

Comment: I believe this immediately. I have another app where I do the same and it works fine. So what makes Android wait 30 seconds in some cases and not in others?

Answer (score 1):

One the weirdest things ever seen in 30 years of software development. The cause of the problem was using elsewhere the deprecated GoogleApiClient for accessing location. This triggered a 30 seconds wait time whenever a server request was sent, but only for some servers. Migrated to FusedLocation and problem disappeared

Comment: "30 seconds" sounds more or less like a default timeout. So this deprecated APIClient may be trying to reach out to a server that doesn't exist anymore and blocking the message queue in the meanwhile ...